# Using a variable from the code behind in a select query

Tags: c#, asp.net, autopostback

I've got a couple drop down lists and I want to make the value of the first DDL determine what fills up the second DDL. I thought maybe I could use autopostback to set the variable to the selected value and then in the second datasource, put it in my select query, like so:

Markup:

```
Select a Category:<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DataTextField="ORG_NAME" DataValueField="ID"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="PopulateDDLsections">
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
Select an Organization:<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOrg" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" DataTextField="SectionName" 
    DataValueField="ID" >
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ORG_SECTIONS] WHERE OrgID = ' + <%= orgID %>'"></asp:AccessDataSource>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/webvideos.mdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ORGANIZATIONS]"></asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class AddRecord : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int orgID = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void PopulateDDLsections(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        orgID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlOrg.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

At first, I got a datatype mismatch, so I changed it to this:

```
protected void PopulateDDLsections(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string orgID = ddlOrg.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

but still got a datatype mismatch error. Is what I'm trying to do as simple as I'm trying to make it? Can I get this way to work?

Comment: why not Int.Parse(SelectedValue);

Comment: What datatype should it be in order to include it in my query?

Comment: it depends on the OrgId column data type, in your database

Comment: First of all, `orgID` must be a class member, not a local variable.

Comment: OrgID is a number field. So then my syntax should be "SELECT * FROM ORG_SECTIONS WHERE OrgID = <%=orgID%>"? When I do that, it tells me I'm missing an operator.

Comment: Yes, no quotes for a number field. As I said - `orgID` should be member of the page class.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use the where clause in the datasource item?

Basic example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tw738475(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the `AccessDataSource2.SelectCommand` within the `PopulateDDLsections()` routine - in the code behind.

Something like:

```
protected void PopulateDDLsections(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int orgID;

    // Make sure we parse the selected value to an int.
    if(Int32.TryParse(ddlOrg.SelectedValue, out orgID))
    {
        // Form the select statement from the orgID we just parsed.
        String command = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [ORG_SECTIONS] WHERE OrgID = {0}", orgID);
        // Assign the SelectCommand.
        AccessDataSource2.SelectCommand = command;
    }

}
```

Comment: and in my markup, I would have "SelectCommand=<%= command %>"?

Comment: I would expect in the markup you could just leave the SelectCommand attribute out altogether - I could be wrong though, haven't used these controls in .NET/C#.

Comment: When I put your code in, it doesn't like the TryParse constructor. It says it has some invalid arguments. I assume it is referring to ddlOrg.SelectedValue, to which I add .ToString and it still didn't like it. Any ideas?

Comment: See edit - orgID should be marked as an out parameter.

Comment: Well, it got the page to load, but nothing shows up in the second DDL :(

Comment: I'm not sure where you are asking me to look. Did you edit your answer? I don't see anything different.